# Tcl variables inside awk (using awk inside Tcl)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, awk, tcl

I need to use awk command inside a Tcl script. I have a file like the following. Let's call it **giri.txt**.

```
1  what
2  Why
3  When
4  who
```

I wrote the following code, thinking it will print like this:

```
what did
why did
when did
who did
```

```
set a did
exec cat giri.txt | awk {{ print $2 " " $a }}
```

But it prints like this:

```
what what
why why
when when
who who
```

Can anyone explain why it's printing like this? Can any one suggest a way to use a Tcl variable inside awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably solve everything tcl without invoking awk, but if you really want to do it:

```
set a did
exec awk "{print \$2, a}" a=$a < giri.txt
```

If you have doubts about how the command will be expanded replace exec by echo and check the result

```
echo awk "{print \$2, a}" a=$a
```

Comment: If we use awk inside tcl ,is the same shell awk code is working ? Or is it a tcl version of awk ?

Comment: A new process is created by `exec`

Comment: if i want to print $a and $2 without space how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it without awk:

```
set a "did"
set stream [open "giri.txt"]
while {[gets $stream line] >= 0} {
  puts "$line $a"
}
close $stream
```

Even better with a reusable procedure:

```
proc forEachLine {file args} {
  set stream [open $file]
  while {[gets $stream line] >= 0} {
    {*}$args $line
  }
  close $stream
}

set a "did"
forEachLine "giri.txt" apply {{line} {
  global a
  puts "$line $a"
}}
```

Comment: The first code, you given is just reading the file line by line and printing it along with $a. It is not selecting the column . To use operations similar to awk, we need somthing like  set fields [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line] . And with awk commad we can do this whole thing bu two lines right ? does it have some performace advantage if we right in Tcl its self

Comment: @GIRIMURALI Less lines of code doesn't neccessary mean less execution time, you'll have to test performance difference. If performance is very important, consider using C. I can think of lots of other disadvantages with calling awk though: Your script will use two processes instead of one, wich is not good on a system where the number of processes are limited. You'll have a harder time debugging two processes. Anyone that maintains the code need to know awk. There may be different versions of awk on different systems, and sometimes no awk at all.